# 100 using only 5 number of digits

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This is a problem from [Martin Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner).

For each digit $1\leq d\leq 9$, make 100 using exactly five number of $i$s. Any operation is allowed, brackets as well.

For $i=1,2$ I have a solution:

> $$100=111-11$$
>
> $$100=(2*2*2+2)^2$$

For the rest, please help.

Comment: In case anyone missed it, the same problem with exactly 6 /i/s is trivial: (iii - ii) / i works for any i in any base > i.

Comment: Hello @Pet123 and welcome to Puzzling.SE. You said that this problem is from Martin Gardner and as such, it would be nice if you can give a link to the problem. Anyways, this is still a good math puzzle. Enjoy your time here :D

Comment: Presumably, $d$ and $i$ refer to the same variable.

Comment: if _any_ operation is allowed, i would like to use the function called hundred, which takes exactly five arguments, and gives constant 100 as a result

Comment: I wonder how [Positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) allows for other approaches here?

Comment: As a tangent, you might be interested in the work of [Inder J. Taneja](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03501.pdf)

Answer (score 29):

Seven

> $100 = 77/.7 - 7/.7$

Six

> $100 = 66/.6 - 6/.6$

Five (and the rest)

> $100 = 55/.5 - 5/.5, \; nn/.n - n/.n$

Comment: Nicely done. Universal solution.

Comment: I wonder whether the use of a decimal point counts as an operation?

Comment: This solution is very nice but the usage of decimal point implicitly uses a 0, because .7 is actually 0.7.

Comment: @rhsquared Arguably, any integer $x$ is actually $x.0$.. ;)

Comment: @JackAidley re: [point counts as an operation?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73628/100-using-only-5-number-of-digits/73637#comment220153_73637): As OP used 3 digits as "111", it implies textual concentration is a legal operation.   Concatenation to the right of the decimal point is just the next step.

Comment: @chux: I find that an unconvincing argument, but since the Asker's specification is vague I shan't pursue the point further. your solution is certainly clever.

Comment: Or even simpler - `(nnn - nn) / n`

Comment: @Rycochet `(nnn - nn) / n` is simpler, yet uses 6 `n`, not  "only 5 number of digits"

Comment: @maxathousand - The `.d` is a typically US notation for values which are `0.d`. Officially the zero is there. A made up notation could be: `10` = `1'`, for `100` = `1''`, `1000` = `1'''`. Sure, you are leaving out writing down the zeroes for `1'''`, but it's still `1000`, just as `.1` = `0.1`. It's a nice answer, if it weren't for this.

Comment: @chux doh - I forgot that bit of it! :-P

Comment: @maxathousand I disagree. Both notations .5 and 0.5 are used around the world. I would vote "better" the one who is less arbitrary. The 0 in 0.5 is generally easier to spot by the eye, but .5 is well-defined too. Having said this, it is a fact that all zeroes included in the prefix and the suffix of a number are useless. You say that in .d the zero is "still there" - Someone else could say that the zeroes of "00.d000" are still there.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis "Someone else could say that the zeroes of "00.d000" are still there." That was the point I was trying to make :) All I was saying was that the padding of zeroes shouldn't reduce this answer's validity because padding with 0 or 500 zeroes in either direction doesn't change the value.

Answer (score 11):

For 9:

> $100 = 99 + (\frac{9}{9})^9$

For 8:

> $100 = 88 + 8 + \sqrt{8+8}$

Answer (score 10):

For $6$

> $\frac {6! - (6 - \frac {6}{6} ) !} {  6} = \frac {6! - 5!}{6} = \frac {720 - 120} {6} = \frac{600}{6} = 100$

Edit: added $7$

> $7!! + \frac{7+7}{7} -7 = (7 \times 5 \times 3) + 2 - 7 = 100$

Comment: Note: $1 ... 5$ and $8 ... 9$ already have uncontroversial solutions posted.

Answer (score 10):

Using [generalized factorial(or multifactorial or k-torial)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations) we obtain:

1:

> 100=11!!!!!!+11!!!!!!!+1

2:

> 100=22!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+(2+2)!/2

3:

> 100=((3!)!!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+3!-(3!+3!)/(3!)

4:

> 100=(4!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+4+(4-4)/4

5:

> 100=(5!!)!!!!!!!!!+5+5+5-5

6:

> 100=(6!!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+6-(6+6)6

7:

> 100=(7!!!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+7!!!!!+(7+7)/7

8:

> 100=(8!!!!+8!!!!!!+(8+8)/8)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

9:

> 100=((9+9/9)!!!!!)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!+9-9

---

So we got 100 using all the i's from 1 to 9.

---

Edit:

I found a formula that works for a any integer greater than 9:

> $$100=\left(\left(\left(\frac{\left(\frac{(n+n){!}_{(n)}}{n+n}\right){\large!}_{(n-5)}}{n}\right){\huge!}_{(3)}\right){\huge!}_{(5)}\right){\huge!}_{(48)}$$
>  where $a!_{(b)}=a\overbrace{!!!\cdots!!!}^{b\mbox{ times}}$

We can write a formula for every number without using $.i$

Comment: Hey @Holo. Welcome to Puzzling.SE and I must say, this is a nice first answer. However, you should check number 5 again. Anyways, happy puzzling :D

Comment: @KevinL oops, forgot to add and subtract ;)

Comment: Nicely done. :D

Comment: $n$ appears 7 times in your last formula. Of course, multiple factorials kill all the fun from such puzzles, so they are usually non accepted.

Comment: @Evargalo no, it appears 7 times for general $n$, but for each specific $n$ it appears 5 times. For example, for $n=57577$ you can using the formula such that $57577$ appears exactly 5 times and you get 100

Comment: Oh ok. Two $n$ are only there to precise the number of exclam signs. Sorry!

Answer (score 8):

One:

> $$ 100=111-11 $$

Two:

> $$ 100=(2*2*2+2)^2 $$

Three:

> $$ \ 100 = \ 33 * 3 + \log_33 $$

Four:

> $$ \ 100 = \ ( \frac{44-4}  4 ) ^ \sqrt4 $$

Five:

> $$ \ 100 = 5 * 5 * 5 - 5 * 5 $$

Six:

> $$ \ 100 = (\log_\sqrt66) ^ 6 + 6 * 6 $$

Seven:

> $$ \ 100 = \ 7 * ( 7 + 7) + \log_\sqrt77 $$

Eight:

> $$ \ 100 = 88 + 8 + \sqrt{8+8} $$

Nine:

> $$ \ 100 = 99 + \log_\sqrt{9*9}9 $$

*logarithms <3*

Comment: Neat 7.  I was wondering how to employ a base change.

Comment: The first whole solution I see. Especially providing the 7s without cheating (floor function or double exponentiation *is* cheating imho) is beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

#### Partial (will update as I figure more out)

For 3:

> 33*3+(3/3)

For 4:

> $4*(4+\frac{4}{4})^\sqrt{4}$

For 5:

> (5*5*5)-(5*5)

For 7: (possibly cheating?)

> ceiling(sqrt(7!)) + ceiling(sqrt(7!)) - (7*7) + 7. you did say any function was allowed.

Comment: 5 could also be (5+5+5+5)*5

Comment: Definitely cheating to use ceiling and floor, I would think.

Comment: I think ceiling and floor is much better than the generalized factorial with 48 exclamation points...

Answer (score 4):

Four

> $100 = (\frac{44 - 4}{4}) ^{\sqrt{4}}$

Answer (score 4):

Four:

> 4 + 4! + 4! + 4! + 4!

Five:

> 5 x 5 x 5 - 5 x 5 or 5 x 5 x (5 - 5/5)

Six:

TBD

Seven:

TBD

Eight:

TBD

Nine:

TBD

Answer (score 2):

*To be improved... Remains the 7s*

For 1 :

> $100=111-11$

For 2:

> $100=(2*2*2+2)^2$

For 3:

> $100=33*3+3/3$

For 4:

> $100=4!*4+4-4+4$

For 5:

> $100=(5+5+5+5)*5$

For 6:

> $100=\frac{6!-\frac{6!}{6}}{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{6}}$

For 7:

> $100=(7+7)*(7+7^\frac{-7}{7})$ (one too many...)

For 8:

> $100=88+8+\sqrt{8+8}$

For 9:

> $100=99+\frac{\sqrt{9}*\sqrt{9}}{9}$

Comment: One extra 9 there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Number 5:

> 5! - (5 + 5 + 5 + 5) = 100
>  (5 + 5) ^ ((5+5)/5) = 100

Answer (score 1):

For some solutions other users were already faster, lets give them credit for it.

3

> 33*3+3/3

4

> 4+4*4!*4/4

5

> (5+5+5+5)*5

6

TODO

7

> It is my cheating. Lets declare a variable `k`
>  k=(7+7)/7, 
>  7*7*k + k 
>  (but I have used `7` 5 times in total anyway)

8

TODO

9

> 99+(sqrt(9)*sqrt(9)/9)

Answer (score 1):

Using a cheaty approach, I have simply tried all permutations of 5 numbers being seperated by 4 operands:

- none, e.g. concat the numbers
- +
- -
- *
- /
- ^
- (
- )
- ^0.5 (Square Root)

I've found solutions for three values of i yet, all of which have of course already been posted:

```
111-11 = 100
33*3+3/3 = 100
3*33+3/3 = 100
3/3+33*3 = 100
3/3+3*33 = 100
5*5*5-5*5 = 100
```

I'll improve my algorithm as I go to include more operands in more locations and edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Seven (almost)

> $100 = (7 + 7) * (7 + \frac{7^0}{7})$

Answer (score 0):

All numbers can be solved with the following:

> 100 = ii / .ii, 1 <= i <= 9

Comment: Yes, but the question wants exactly 5 is.

Answer (score 0):

For i=2,9

●((2)^2)^2+92 = 100

Some randoms,

●9^2 + 5^2 - 6 = 100

●2*(3^2)+ 82 =100

Comment: Hello @neh and welcome to PSE. Nice answer however, the question seems to only allow 1 number in each equation. Using both 2 and 9 in 1 equation, like yours, is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another UNIVERSAL solution

> Antilog ( n+n/(n+n-n) ) = 100
>  
>  Example
>  
>  Antilog ( 2+2/(2+2-2)) = 100

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Antilog ( n+n/(n+n-n) )`?  The idea being that antilog in this case means `10^x`, so if you can get `x=2`, you can make 100 every time.  Or am I misunderstanding what antilog means?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned the following "solution" using five zeroes:

> $0! : (0 \times 0) : (0 + 0) = 1 : 0 : 0 = 100$, where $:$ means concatenation (e.g. $2:8=28$). It works because all operations are explicitly allowed  (I think, at least all *standard*, i.e. not *specifically* invented for this problem, ones are - and concatenation is obviously standard under this definition)

Comment: The question said "For each digit  $1 ≤ d ≤ 9$".